# Generating data according to rules in python

Tags: python

I'm working on a sharding problem, and I need to ensure that the servers covering the shards have the following properties:

1. A primary and a secondary server is nominated to host each shards.
2. The primary and secondary server for each shard should be in separate data centers.
3. The shards should be relatively evenly distributed across each server.

I poked around and that sounds like a rules framework would be useful. I dug into Pyke but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to frame the above in the rules Pyke exposes.  Am I barking up the wrong tree?  Any other recommendations?

Comment: Not a software shopping problem, am afraid. You should be looking for an algorithm first.

Answer (score -1):

[Pyke](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/examples.html) looks like the [wrong tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917607/relational-logic-programming-in-python) to me, hence this alternative: [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/)

If you can provide (user-)generated content for new areas, you can have everything in one big shard:

> Have you ever wondered why MMOs have multiple servers and limitations
>   on the number of people that can be squeezed onto each? It's a good
>   question, especially when you consider EVE Online's impressive
>   single-shard (single-server) setup, where tens of thousands of
>   concurrent players can log on in the same environment.
>    - [A look into the nuts-and-bolts of EVE Online's single-shard architecture](http://massively.joystiq.com/2010/08/10/a-look-into-the-nuts-and-bolts-of-eve-onlines-single-shard-arch/)

Stackless Python threads can be hibernated and distributed across multiple machines, if needed.

Comment: Please explain the downvotes.